# Display post excerpt instead of content, if available

Tags: excerpt

I'm planning to display the post excerpt instead of the content if available and auto generate excerpt from the content if not available with the function below:

```
<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'blabla' ) ); ?>
```

in `functions.php` I'm adding:

```
# Function to trim the excerpt
if (!function_exists('narga_excerpts')) :
    function narga_excerpts($content = false) {
        # If is the home page, an archive, or search results
            global $post;
            $excerpt_length = 40;
        # If an excerpt is set in the Optional Excerpt box
        if ( $post->post_excerpt ) {
        $content = the_excerpt();
        function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
            return 20;
        }
        add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
        function excerpt_readmore($more) {
        return '... <a title="' . the_title_attribute('echo=0') . '" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '" class="more-link">  ' . __( 'Read more &#187;', 'narga' ) . ' </a>';
        }
            add_filter('excerpt_more', 'excerpt_readmore');
        }
        # If no excerpt is set
        else {
            $content = $post->post_content;
            $words = explode(' ', $content, $excerpt_length + 1);
            if(count($words) > $excerpt_length) {
                array_pop($words);
                $content = implode(' ', $words);
            }
        }
        $content = '<p>' . $content . '</p>';
        # Make sure to return the content
        return $content;
    }
# Replace content with excerpt
add_filter('the_content', 'narga_excerpts');
endif;
```

But it does not work.

Comment: "But it's not works" is useless. Tell us what it does that you are not expecting and/or what doesn't do that you are expecting it to do.

Comment: Sorry about little information, at the line 9 `$content = the_excerpt();` the problem is this line, the function will check if the excerpt exist then the valua of `$content` is the post excerpt that I can filte like default excerpt. But I can't find the correct solution to do it.
Current function will drive WordPress to infinite loop then the browser get the reset error only.

Answer (score 2):

Change line 9 to:

```
$content = get_the_excerpt();
```

[the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) echoes the excerpt. [get_the_excerpt()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_excerpt) returns it.